# Asus Pro P550ca Trackpad unresponsive, cursor moving leftwards every 20 seconds

Tags: mouse, touchpad, asus, cursor

Well I have finally decided to start fresh and move from using mac to using Ubuntu and I have bought the following computer to begin my linux journey with:
Asus Pro P550CA-XO330D

I have successfully install Ubuntu now and it appears that everything is working except the trackpad, and even when only using a usb mouse, there is the problem that the mouse often does not actually click on what is underneath it and the cursor moves to the left about every 20 seconds. The trackpad itself is about 95 percent unresponsive. I think maybe for an advanced linux user this may not seem like much of a problem, but as a beginner I honestly could not have a clue where to start to have this sort of problem fixed. I have installed Ubuntu 14.0 and installed all the available software updates as of July 21st 2014.

Comment: Please, if someone could even tell me just what is actually going on here that would be amazing. I am really completely lost with this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the touchpad is not yet supported by the kernel. Details can be found [in the Bugtracker for issue #77391](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77391).

There is a workaround for now to at least use the touchpad as a simple mouse. You need to add `psmouse.proto=bare` to your kernel command line.

Comment: These touchpads are already supported. But OP did not give information on which touchpad is there.